# ActivatedRoute always pointing to root in NgRx Effect

Tags: angular, routes, ngrx, effects, angular-activatedroute

I am trying to figure out why my ActivatedRoute in an ngrx effect is always pointing to root, its ".url" always return Observable of `path: ''`.

Comment: That is expected. An activated route is only set for routed components while an effect is a service. However, there is a nice solution for this in NgRx: https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store